# Do carbon resistors generate heat in a properly working circuit?

Tags: pcb, resistance, heat, calculation

Do resistors in a circuit generate heat based on their resistance value?

Can anybody explain how resistors drop voltage without generating heat?

Comment: I am trying to understand how carbon resister drop voltage in a circuit? I understand it drop voltage basis on resistance value, in this action any heat generating by carbon resister?

Comment: Research heating effect of electricity.

Comment: All resistors dissipate heat, even if you cannot feel it.  The closer the power is to rated power, the hotter the resistor.

Answer (score 6):

Resistors do generate heat, and it is not dependent on their material or resistance. It's the power dissipated in them, which does depend on voltage and current, which are related by the resistance.

Answer (score 5):

> if we use many resisters in a circuit, is this all resisters generate heat to basis on its resistance value?

No. Resistors generate heat on the basis of the power they are dissipating. There are three ways of writing the power, knowing two of the three parameters V, I and R.

$$P=VI \space \textrm{or} \space P=I^2R \space \textrm{or} \space P=\frac{V^2}{R} $$

Given the definition of resistance as V/I, all three forms are equivalent. We generally choose which we use for convenience, and for which things tend to be constant in our situation. For instance, if it's a resistor across a power supply, then V will tend to be constant, and we will use the first or third form. If we have a constant current passing through a resistor, then the second form might be more convenient.

> can anybody explain how resister drop voltage with out generating heat?

No, because that's not what happens.

If a resistor has a voltage drop across it, it will be generating heat. If the voltage drop is small, or the current is low, then the amount of heat might be undetectable as temperature rise to a probing finger.

Comment: Is this heat we consider Ohmic heat?  In my practical experience, if we choose wrong resistance value in carbon resister it usually generate heat, but correct value  (R=V/I)  it wont generate heat.

Comment: @user2465357: as Neil_UK said, if there is voltage across it, the resistor (whatever it is made of) will generate heat. But e.g. a 1 mega-ohm resistor with 1V across it will generate a micro-watt of heat - you can't measure that (outside a lab), certainly can't feel that with your fingers.